# Using a different PHP file to create part of the page

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a bar on the top of the page and depending if the user is logged in or not, have separate messages i.e. You are not currently logged in.

When I try it out it displays the message but not the black box or the form that is supposed to be there.

Here you can see what is being outputted:

[image: What is coming out]

And how its suppost to look like:
[image: How its supposed to look like]

Is there a way to make it so that the image above is at the top of every page. I tried using include at the top of the script but it doesn't work however. Here is the code to produce this the desired output:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/login_bar.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="loginBar" class="loginBar">
    <p><span style="float:left; margin-left:5px">You are not currently   logged on.</span> <?php login(); ?></p>
</div>

<?php

    function login(){
        echo "<form action=\"user_login_check.php\" method=\"get\"   style=\"float:right;margin-right:5px\">";
        echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" placeholder=\"Username\">  ";
        echo " <input type=\"text\" name=\"password\" placeholder=\"Password\"> ";
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Submit\">";
        echo "</form>";
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

I've noticed that when I turn this all to php and echo everything it doesn't work.

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../../css/login_bar.css' />";
echo "<div id=\"loginBar\" class=\"loginBar\">";
if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])){
    echo "<p><span style=\"float:left; margin-left:5px\">You are not currently logged on.</span> php login(); </p>";
}else{
    echo "<p><span style=\"float:left; margin-left:5px\">Welcome, ".$_SESSION['user']."</span> php login();</p>";
}
echo "</div><br>";

function login(){
    echo "<form action=\"user_login_check.php\" method=\"get\" style=\"float:right;margin-right:5px\">";
    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" placeholder=\"Username\">  ";
    echo " <input type=\"text\" name=\"password\" placeholder=\"Password\"> ";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Submit\">";
    echo "</form>";
}

?>
```

Is there a way to call this file and this bar be produced or am I going to have to input the code on each page?

**EDITS**

I've changed the code in the second segment to what the code is currently (no ), the form has showed up (YAY) but the surronding black box hasn't

Comment: [Read the first note](http://php.net/session_start): if you're using multiple PHP files, it's important to make sure there's absolutely **no** output before you call `session_start`, not even whitespace before the opening `<?php` tag

Comment: I don't believe there is any white space, I have the form part working its just the black box from the second picture that is not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to open php tag, when you already in a php tag
this:

```
echo "<p><span style=\"float:left; margin-left:5px\">You are not currently logged on.</span> <?php login(); ?></p>";
```

should be something like this

```
echo "<p><span style=\"float:left; margin-left:5px\">You are not currently logged on.</span>";
login(); 
echo "</p>";
```

for the other:

```
echo "<p><span style=\"float:left; margin-left:5px\">Welcome, ".$_SESSION['user']."</span> <?php login(); ?></p>";
```

you did the same so change it to:

```
echo "<p><span style=\"float:left; margin-left:5px\">Welcome, ".$_SESSION['user']."</span>";
login();
echo "</p>";
```

But I think it is useless to show the login form for someone who is logged in.

Comment: Thank you, this makes the form part show up (its a working progress so I will be changing the form to a logout button in the future). However its not making the bar black. Is there something wrong with how I'm referencing the css?

Comment: @MrHappySandwich show you  css file and folder structure edit you question

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with the css, its just a bit of code to make the box black. When I go on the php file directly it is exactly how I want it, however when I call it from another file it doesn't show the colour of the box i.e. like the first picture.

Answer (score 0):

i dont have time to figure out the mistakes you doing but i can tell the correct way.

```
> <?PHP 
>      session_start();
>     if(!isset($_SEEION['user']))
>      {  ?>    <body>
>       <p>Your are currently not Logged In.</p>
>       <form>Then put the html form here...</form>
>     <?php
>      }
>     else
>     {
>       echo 'Welcome '.$_SESSION['user'].' You are logged in';
>      }    

   ?>        </body>
```

Comment: Well I want to be able to include this file so that any page that calls the php file will have the black box at the top. I've got most of it working however there isn't the black box when it is called from a different file, just the message and form.

Comment: I've done that and it worked, I'm not building a big site, just one with a bunch of scripts that people can use to make their job easier. I will keep the MVC model in mind in the future however.

Answer (score 0):

`<?php` tag is already open, you don't need to reopen it again when calling the `login()` function.

use the following lines

```
echo '<p><span style="float:left; margin-left:5px">You are not currently logged on.</span>'.login().'</p>';
```

and

```
echo '<p><span style="float:left; margin-left:5px">Welcome, '.$_SESSION['user'].'</span>'.login().'</p>';
```

Comment: I've done that and the form part is showing now,  however the black box isn't showing up

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix the black box not showing. I had to (in the page I wanted it on) add the link to the css there and have the include file in the body and this showed the black box, here is the code:

```
<?php
    require_once "./utility/login/login_check.php";
//  include "./testing/user_login/user_login.php";  Previous location
 ?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='./css/login_bar.css' /> //added this part
</head>
<body>
<?php
    include "./testing/user_login/user_login.php";//New location

?>
<p><a href="./testing/testing.php">Testing</a><br><br>
<a href="./outreach/outreach.php">Outreach</a><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```